# Live css module won't save my css

Tags: 7

I am using the live css module, but when I try to save the css on the fly I get the error message 'The url used contains a sub-filextension which poses a security threat. Saving not allowed.'
Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: what is the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated by the following code in the module

```
  if (file_munge_filename($sanitized_url, 'css less') != $sanitized_url) {
    echo drupal_json_encode(array(
      'result' => 'failure',
      'filename' => $href,
      'msg' => 'The url used contains a sub-filextension which poses a security threat. Saving not allowed.'
    ));
```

This checks passes the sanitized url through the [file_munge_filename](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_munge_filename/7) function. The function checks for all the extensions in the file adds an underscore after the extension to make it secure. you can read the link for more information.

So I presume that there is some issue with the css file you are uploading. there might be more than 1 extension in the file name such as style.abc.css.